# I am writing a python script for chatbot and i am getting this error

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\dsp\OneDrive\Documents\VS code\main.py", line 6, in 
import tflearn
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tflearn_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 40, in 
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
PS C:\Users\dsp\OneDrive\Documents\VS code> python -u "c:\Users\dsp\OneDrive\Documents\VS code\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\dsp\OneDrive\Documents\VS code\main.py", line 6, in 
import tflearn
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tflearn_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 40, in 
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python 38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please include the code that yield the error or at least how we can reproduce this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Whenever you have an issue and want some help, you should look at look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, in order to formulate a "quality question". Basically, you need to add your code, and investigate by your own before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019.](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Install all the System requirements mentioned
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements.

Install the 64-bit Python 3 release for Windows